# How to toggle between two string values like boolean True/False inside AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have a button, clicking on it should show/hide some area.

```
button(ng-click="areaStatus='on'")
.area(ng-class="areaStatus")
```

I want not to just use ng-show/ng-hide and then assign it to Boolean areaStatus, but I want more complex things like on/off/hidden/transparent/whatever.

Is there a way to toggle areaStatus between 'on' and 'off' on click without having to write a function for it, just with an inline expression?

Comment: can't you use ng-switch in that case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this (HTML):

```
<button ng-click="value = { 'on': 'off', 'off':'on'}[value]">On/Off</button>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvpwX/)

But it's very ugly. I would definitely create a method on the scope to change the state, especially if it's more complicated than just toggling two values.

However, if `areaStatus` is just to change the area class, I think you should drop it, and instead change the class accordingly to your model state. Something like this:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.state = 'on';

    $scope.changeState = function() {
        $scope.state = $scope.state === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on';
    }
}

...

<area ng-class="{'on': state, 'off': !state }">
```

I've used 'on' and 'off', but it should be values that make sense to your model.

Comment: I was stumped when the ternary operator `$scope.state = 'on' ? 'off' : 'on';` wasn't working. I was missing the additional `$scope.state ===`. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

It's not too clear what you're wanting or why you are avoiding wanting a function, but a way that I'd go about doing what I think you want to do:

```
<button ng-click="areaStatus = !areaStatus">Toggle</button>
<div ng-class="{'red' : areaStatus, 'green' : !areaStatus}">
    This is some text
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle that shows it as well](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/mgPGS/1/) as well as a code snippet below.

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.areaStatus = false;
});
```

```css
.red {
    color:red;
}
.green {
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <button ng-click="areaStatus = !areaStatus">Toggle</button>
        <div ng-class="{'red' : areaStatus, 'green' : !areaStatus}">
            This is some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Within the `ng-click` you just simply flip the `boolean` value of `areaStatus`. With `ng-class` you can pass in an object. The `red` and `green` would be the classes that you want to apply. They will be applied when the expression following is correct.

An alternative would be to use Angular's `{{ }}` within your class:

```
<div class="{{areaStatus}}">   </div>
```

So if `areaStatus` contains the string `"hidden"`, then that is what class will be in there. But you'd still need a way to then change the value of `areaStatus` (either in a function, multiple buttons, or checkboxes).

Answer (score 0):

I think inline change is a good idea:

```
(ngModelChange)="data.is_toggole=(data.is_toggole== 0 ? 0 : 1)"
```

data.is_toggole //Your variable